# Meaning of 小動物系

Tags: meaning, slang, internet-slang, metaphor

Context: a man reads some online posts after accusing another man of being a pedofile.

[image]

What is the meaning of 小動物系? Considering the context and the fact that images of young girls came out when I tried to look for it on Google Images, I think the meaning is not simply "small animals system".

Also, could you explain the meaning of 裏ＤＶＤ and "こマ!？"? I think that the first means "illegal DVDs", while te second sounds to me like "really?!". Is it correct? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**小動物系**

In this case 系 doesn't mean *system*. Instead it refers to a certain category of girls. 小動物系 describes girls you could compare to small animals in terms of cuteness. They obviously can't be tall or overweight, but they also must behave in a certain lovely manner. You can read more about this use of 系 [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4572/defining-a-particular-%E7%B3%BB).

**裏ＤＶＤ**

You're right, these are DVDs that can't be sold in the open. Specifically, the term nearly always refers to sexual videos.

**こマ!?**

This is a shortening of これマジ!?, which indeed means *really?!* \ *are you serious?!*.